valid/enable flow control of a pipelined system
This diagram describes the nature of the digital design. It takes in data that passes through N stage pipeline and goes to the output.

Data enters the pipeline in when i_valid adn i_ready are both high.
Data exits the pipeline and is registered downstream when the o_valid and o_ready are both asserted.
The data coming into the pipeline is intermittent. The downstream module intermittently asserts o_ready. This means that the data stream is intermittent.
My conclusions so far.

i_ready; this signal is high after reset. It will stay high unless the pipeline has data at the stage N but o_ready is not asserted. The i_ready is not registered and is function of o_ready.
o_valid; this is asserted when the stage N has valid data. Otherwise it shall remain low.
cke (clock enable) for the pipelined stages; this is supposed to be high when any stage of the pipeline has valid data. The only exception is when the data reaches stage N and o_ready is low. Then the cke must remain low.
The actual pipeline has arithmetic logic operations taking place in each stage. I assume that I must create another shift register chain that shall contain "data_valid" in it. If data_valid of any shift register output is high, clock enable for entire pipeline is high. Else the clock enable is low. This can be used to generate o_valid.
The first "data_valid" is equal to i_valid & i_ready i.e handshake.

Is my understanding of pipelined system design complete? I still need to see if I need skid buffer or not.

The simplest processing pipeline is what I call a "rigid pipeline". It has no internal flow control — all of the stages either advance or hold together.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Yes, you do need to carry the VALID signal along with the data at each stage of the pipeline.
The READY signal from the sink on the right directly controls the clock enables of all of the registers in the pipeline, and it also directly drives the READY input of the source on the left.
It sounds from some of your questions that you would also like this pipeline to function as a FIFO, with data from the left propagating as far as it can into the pipeline until it gets blocked by data that hasn't yet been accepted on the right.
While it's certainly possible to build a pipeline that has flow control at every stage and works like that, I have found that it creates problems either by creating a long chain of combinatorial logic in the READY chain, or by increasing the overall latency of the pipeline.
But if you really need that functionality, I have found that it's far better to simply put an ordinary FIFO at the output of the rigid pipeline described above. It simplifies the design of both pieces, and now the depth of the FIFO can be independent of the depth of the processing pipeline.

Lets see, if I put a FIFO at the output on the right, how does the valid/enable work? I guess the valid becomes write_enable into the FIFO and the ready becomes "not full"?

Yes. I was assuming based on the READY/VALID terminology that you were using that you were talking about AXI stream protocol, or something very much like it. So you would stick a standard AXI stream FIFO at the output of this rigid pipe.

The scenario I am dealing with uses TLAST as well since the data is grouped into packets.

But incorporating that should not be difficult.

By the way, have you used skid buffers?

Yes, TLAST can be carried through the rigid pipe in the same way that VALID is. And yes, regarding skid buffers, see the discussion here and this answer.

I was writing the RTL code and then suddenly I realized something so here is the question. If the i_valid is low, there is no data going in. So why is the clock enable not equal to i_valid & o_ready?

It's perfectly OK to have the clock enabled even when i_valid is false. That's why we carry TVALID through the pipeline -- to keep track of which stages contain useful data and which  do not. We want any valid data to continue to propagate through the pipe, stopping only if the module connected to the output can't accept new data.

I have completed the RTL code and written the testbench. Now making bug fixes. One of the pipelined stages contains counter. Counter gives address. The address goes into a ROM. ROM output is registered. The output of the ROM goes into multiplier. The other input to multiplier is registered TDATA. The counter only need count up when the input data is valid on a clock cycle. When input data is valid and TLAST too, the counter needs to reset. So the question is, do I use just cke everywhere, or the counter need to use cke and also TAVLID (input)? I am curious about your opinion.

All flip-flops within the pipeline, including counters, need to be clock-enabled.

yes, the design is complete and appears to work correctly
